# How to apply Ink.image() on CachedNetworkImage()?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-image

I want my image to have inkwell effect when tapped, previously I could do that with Ink.image widget and then Provide NetworkImage() as image attribute like this:

```dart
Ink.image(
    fit: BoxFit.fitWidth,
    image: NetworkImage(
      product.imageUrl,
    ),
),
```

But now I want to use CachedNetworkImage() because it has placeholder property to show loading status of my network image but the problem is when I use cachedNetworkImage i can no longer wrap this widget with ink.image because it requires image as an attrubute not any other widget.

Answer (score 4):

`Ink.image` constructor requires `image` param to be a `ImageProvider`, not a widget. You can use `CachedNetworkImageProvider` instead of `CachedNetworkImage` like this:

```
Ink.image(
    fit: BoxFit.fitWidth,
    image: CachedNetworkImageProvider(
       product.imageUrl,
   )
),
```

However with this you'll lose placeholder capacity. However you can use `CachedNetworkImageProvider` [createStream](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/painting/ImageProvider/createStream.html) method to get an `ImageStream` that can be listened for errors and completion, with which you can create your own custom widget that updates the UI based on this stream.

Answer (score 4):

You can use the `imageBuilder` from the `CachedNetworkImage` and pass the `imageProvider` to `Ink.image`.

Here's a sample code.

```dart
CachedNetworkImage(
  imageUrl: "$imagePath",
  imageBuilder: (context, imageProvider) {
    return Ink.image(
      image: imageProvider,
      fit: fit,
    );
  },
)
```